# Yet another (#5) Unauthorized source IP address

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I've read all other question regarding this issue, but could not find a solution. I modified the IP whitelist in the facebook app settings to include the server by which the API is being called, but after I do so, I get an even more worrying "This IP can't make requests for that application." when trying to use the Facebook API from my web app.

The odd thing is that it was working till yesterday, when last user signed up and logged in via Facebook into the app.

Today, all of a sudden, my web application is not authorized anymore?

?

Comment: Most likely is that your server is doing requests with a different IP. Maybe an IPv6 address

Comment: No, I tried putting the IPv6 version of the IP address in the white list and it's the same.

Comment: Hey! Lesson learned here I guess! I had converted my server IP to a IPv6 version with a conversion calculator! I thought that IPv6 for my server had to simply be an IPv4 mapped to a IPv6 while what I see is that the converted IPv6 is different than the one that I have in the VPS control panel! So... when I used the one from control panel in the facebook app IP white list, it started working again... So thank you I guess! :) I still got a thing or two to learn about IPv6's ;) but... then why it was working before, without neither IPv4 or v6 in the whitelist (it was blank) ? ... Mhmm... ideas?

Comment: If no ip is there then any ip is allowed

Comment: I know but my point was that initially with no IP's in whitelist it was working, then it was not, then I entered the correct IPv6 (not the IPv4 converted to a IPv6) and it worked. But turns out this was just a coincidence. Facebook just told me that they had blacklisted my IP temporarily... ... (I will update my own answer on this)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I received from Facebook Platform Team

> The IP address from which you're trying to use the Facebook API from
>   is blacklisted, because someone else using the same IP address has
>   recently violated the Facebook API Terms of Service. Your only option
>   is to obtain a different IP address to use with the Graph API.

was not very helpful, but I was making a silly mistake myself: the server was communicating with the Facebook API using its IPv6 address, and I was aware of this, but instead of using the proper IPv6 address for the server, I was converting the server IPv4 address to an IPv6 address and using that value, because that's how I thought that IPv6's are getting assigned.... (out of plain ignorance or genius ;) )

Comment: well...it´s most likely not facebooks fault if someone violated the facebook terms, you know... ;)

Comment: Please don't turn upside down the logic of my implicit statements. I am not saying it's facebook fault if someone violated their terms, but it's their fault if they just tell me "Hey kid, go get another IP, we are not allowing it anymore" even though I did nothing wrong.

Comment: why is it their fault? they don´t just block something for no reason.

Answer (score 1):

The reputation problem with shared IPV4 addresses is going to get far worse when the carriers are forced to use CGNAT for IPV4 addresses when the IPV4 address pool runs out.  The IPV4 address pool in North America is expected to run out in Q1 2015.  It has already run out in South America, Europe, and Asia.  Currently IPV4 addresses are shared through time (the IPV4 address the belonged to me yesterday belongs to you today, and may belong to that person over there next week.).  With CGNAT, the IPV4 address that I am using at the moment may be the same IPV4 address that you are using right now as well.  This means that if one of us violates TOS, all of us may be restricted.

IPV6 should not have this problem.  They are so sparsely allocated that the /64 you are using now should be yours for a long time, and even if it does change, you are unlikely to get one that anyone else is using, or has used in the last several years.